# How to access other people's company history with current V2 LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'd like to ask if it is even possible to access other LinkedIn member's employment history using V2 API.

This resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/marketing/context#person-id) says that "The use of this API is restricted to those developers approved by LinkedIn and subject to applicable data restrictions in their agreements".

So I do have to apply for LinkedIn's approval for my app, right?

Moreover, section "Retrieve Other Member's Profile" says that "To retrieve another member's profile, you will need access to the Person ID, available only via certain limited access APIs and subject to member privacy settings".

This is also very unclear to me how to do this.

So again, the main question is:
is it possible to access other member's employment history via V2 API?

Comment: did you find a way to become a developers approved by LinkedIn?